# Geeting cant resolve "fs" in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

While learning react I am getting these errors please help me out

> WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
>       Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>        @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
>        @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
>        @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
>        @ ./app/components/HeaderLoggedIn.js
>        @ ./app/components/Header.js
>        @ ./app/Main.js

```
My webpack.config.js file is 

    const path = require("path")

    module.exports = {
      entry: "./app/Main.js",
      output: {
        publicPath: "/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
        filename: "bundled.js"
      },
      mode: "development",
      devtool: "source-map",
      devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: { index: "index.html" }
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-react", ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "12" } }]]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you currently are including `express` back-end dependency in a front-end project?

Comment: right what to do next ?

Comment: Well, your react front-end should not depend on `express`, which uses `fs` node module internally. How does `dependencies` in package.json look like?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }

Comment: Dear I am using an API and connected to backend so i really need express

Comment: You might take a look at [some starters](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+express+starter&oq=react+express+starter) to compare it with your project.